# Unable get my wireless network connection under awesome window manager?

Tags: window-manager

Unable get my wireless network connection when I switched to awesome window manager. However, automatically I get wireless connection under Ubuntu 11.04 classic. Could someone tell me how to get wireless connection under awesome window manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A program called NetworkManager has been the default network configuration mechanism on Ubuntu for some time now. Several front-ends for the desktop-agnostic backend exist, but primarily there are cli, Gnome, and KDE variants. Wikipedia lists several [NetworkManager front ends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager#User_interfaces). GTK-based window managers usually use nm-applet, and an independent wiki gives instructions on [using nm-applet with the awesome window manager](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Nm-applet).

(incidentally, that link is hosted through naquadah.org, and I'm in the middle of a Stargate episode :P)

Comment: When I click the nm-applet link, firefox is saying that the connection is untrusted. Please provide me a valid link. Thanks.

Comment: @kkp Are you aware there is no danger there?  Most sites are not secured.  Just proceed and remember not to upload confidential info like your credit card number .... :/

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh What differentiates [that site](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Nm-applet) from sites that are not secured is that it *does* use https, but its certificate is not issued by a recognized certificate authority. Ordinarily a site that uses HTTPS is expected to be trusted, and in situations like this, it's eminently reasonable for people to assume there may be something wrong with the site.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to check the network-manager service status. Press Mod4(super key) and Enter/Return key and type this commands:

```
sudo service network-manager status
```

If it is up and running, next, check the available wifi networks:

```
nmcli connection show
```

to connect:

```
nmcli connection up <NAME OF WIFI NETWORK>
```